# ITunesConnect dont display additional languages on submit for review

Tags: ios, localization, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

I use Unty 4.6 Beta 20, XCode 6.1.
I created app with unity3d and currently want upload it to app store.
I dont use xcode(ios) localisation functionality, because unity provides own framework for localisation.
So i dont have any languages metadata in xcode project.
I uploaded binary in ITunes Connect and than start localise appstore description and screenshots.
But languages list contains only 9 languages.(I need Russian and Ukrainian, which dont contains in languages list)
[image: ITunes connect languages list]

After that i read in apple doc's, that i should add language metadata in xcode project for make it visible in itunes connect(why i dont do this for Brazilian, Danish, etc?).

I added languages in XCode project file
[image: Xcode project language settings]

And in plist file

[image: Plist language list]

As you can se, xcode recognise "en" as English, but dont recognise ru and uk, as Russian and Ukrainian.
Also if i click on it, combo box will not have languages which i need.
[image: Plist language popup]

After this i will upload new binary to itunes connect, but it still dont show Russian and Ukrainian in languages list.

My project structure:
[image: iOS project structure]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The languages you configure in iTunes Connect is only for localizing the *description* of the app on App Store, so it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the languages you work with *inside* you app code.

If you handle all localization of your UI inside Unity anyway, there's no need to alter any files in the generated Xcode project.

In Itunes Connect, you can only choose from a handful of languages to have different languages in app title, description, keywords and screenshots. It doesn't seem that iTunes Connect supports Ukrainian at all, but Russian is there. (Make sure that you have made your app available in the respective app stores). Again, this has nothing to do with which languages your app can display once it is installed and running.

Included is my iTunes Connect for a new app, with the language selector scrolled down to the bottom.

EDIT: (thanks to lnjuanj)

It might seem that your browser doesn't show the scrollbar in the ITC language list properly. Apple always assumes that you view their developer content in the Safari browser.

[image: iTunes Connect languages]

Comment: Thanks! You save me a lot of time! It really terrible for me, just not user friendly interface.

Comment: "Make sure that you have made your app available in the respective app stores" - How exactly do you do this? My app has no restriction on the territory, but when a friend of mine from another country opened my app, it display in English.

Answer (score 1):

Language metadata dropdown doesn't appear as it should in your browser.

You should change to another browser because there are tens of languages. That is independent of your Xcode project.

Comment: Yes! Always remember that Apple doesn't care how their developer sites look in any other browser than Safari.